# How to get all the values stored in the new add category attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, category-attribute

I followed some instructions to do "Add new Image attribute for category in magento 2" and I was successful.and now I want to output all newly added images printed out in the same place on all pages can someone help me to solve this problem. Thank for all

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Category Model for this. For example, your category Id is **10** and your custom attribute is **category_new_image**. Check the below code as per this configuration:

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryId = 10;
$category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
$category_new_image = $category->getCategoryNewImage(); // your custom attribute value
echo $category_new_image;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Try this code**

```
protected $_categoryFactory;

protected $_storeManager;

protected $_categoryNameFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryNameFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collecionFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_categoryNameFactory = $categoryNameFactory;
    $this->_categoryFactory = $collecionFactory;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


public function getCategoryWithImage()
{
    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->addAttributeToFilter('Your_Attribute_code',['neq' => 'NULL'])->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore());
    return $category;
}

public function getCategoryName($categoryId)
{
    $category = $this->_categoryNameFactory->create()->load($categoryId)->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore());
    return $category;
}
```